# JPA get id of entity object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Does anyone know how I can do the equivalent of this in hibernate:

```
session.getIdentifier(instance);
```

with JPA?

EntityManager has a contains method but that's pretty much it!

I'm writing some code that acts as a transformer between entities and data stored in a session (so rather than a serialized object being stored just the class name and the id is stored).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I can do the equivalent of this in hibernate (...) with JPA?

JPA 1.0 doesn't have an equivalent so if you're stuck with JPA 1.0, you'll have to use Hibernate's API: obtain the `Session` from the `EntityManager` and use [`Session#getIdentitifier(Object)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.Object%29).

For example, with JBoss (yes, `getDelegate()` is [not portable](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/05/25/be-careful-while-using-entitymanagergetdelegate)):

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session)manager.getDelegate();
session.getIdentifier(myEntity);
```

If you are using JPA 2.0, then use [`PersistenceUnitUtil#getIdentity(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceUnitUtil.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.Object%29) as suggested by [axtavt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106925/jpa-get-id-of-entity-object/4107005#4107005). But that's not available in JPA 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The non-portable solution should work fine hopefully as a temporary fix.

Answer (score 21):

In JPA 2.0 you can write

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(instance);
```

Comment: +1 (I was searching through the depths of MetaModel and EntityType, but it never occurred to me to look inside EntityManagerFactory).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to think about upgrading to JPA 2.0.