# Hibernate Restrictions.in() only accepts propertyName as String

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a List of ids:

```
List<Object> ids;
```

I need to use this in a criteria query to get all rows with an id that `ids` contains.

What I have now and works:

```
    if (ids.size() > 0) {
        for (Object id : ids) {
            preparedResults.add((T)sessionMngr.getSession().
                    createCriteria(rowType).add(Restrictions.idEq(id))
                    .uniqueResult());
        }
    }
```

So I fetch them one by one, which isn't optimal, but I first tried something like following to get them in one query, but don't know what to put at the *???*:

```
            preparedResults.addAll(sessionMngr.getSession().
                createCriteria(rowType).
                add(Restrictions.in(???, ids)).list());
```

The first argument of *Restrictions.in()* is of type String. I can't put a hard coded "id" there as I don't know what the propertyname is.
So I don't know how to get the id property as a String there.
I saw Projections.id(), but I am not sure if I can use this to get it as a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this [solution](http://www.altuure.com/2010/10/25/retrieving-id-field-from-jpa-and-hibernate/) you can retrieve the name of the id field of your entity. If you use annotations you can have it even shorter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647549/how-to-get-the-field-annotated-with-id-in-ejb3-jpa-and-hibernate). If you don´t use composite primary keys you could also use

`ClassMetadata classMetadata = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(myClass);
string identifierPropertyName = classMetadata.getIdentifierPropertyName();`

Source of this snippet: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647549/how-to-get-the-field-annotated-with-id-in-ejb3-jpa-and-hibernate)